# Не отображается SVG файл

Tags: svg, svg-спрайт

Подключение в HTML:

```html
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 474.986 474.986" style="enable-background:new 0 0 474.986 474.986;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_3_" d="M440.904,356.937l-15.139-80.104c-0.632-3.32-2.842-6.123-5.93-7.501c-3.081-1.386-6.647-1.163-9.542,0.577
    l-69.815,42.086c-4.09,2.464-5.954,7.408-4.514,11.952c1.434,4.552,5.799,7.515,10.559,7.184l27.269-1.902
    c-26.037,34.993-65.227,49.355-110.178,53.036V153.103h22.449c3.62,2.695,8.07,4.343,12.929,4.343
    c12.021,0,21.771-9.742,21.771-21.764c0-12.029-9.75-21.771-21.771-21.771c-4.867,0-9.318,1.656-12.938,4.351h-22.441V86.789
    c12.776-8.494,21.231-22.987,21.231-39.436C284.845,21.247,263.6,0,237.493,0c-26.107,0-47.354,21.247-47.354,47.353
    c0,16.449,8.456,30.942,21.231,39.436v31.474h-22.44c-3.62-2.695-8.07-4.351-12.937-4.351c-12.021,0-21.771,9.742-21.771,21.771
    c0,12.021,9.75,21.764,21.771,21.764c4.859,0,9.309-1.648,12.929-4.343h22.448v229.162c-44.95-3.681-84.14-18.043-110.176-53.036
    l27.269,1.902c4.759,0.331,9.125-2.632,10.558-7.184c1.44-4.543-0.423-9.488-4.513-11.952l-69.816-42.086
    c-2.896-1.74-6.461-1.963-9.542-0.577c-3.088,1.378-5.298,4.181-5.93,7.501l-15.14,80.104c-0.886,4.689,1.555,9.372,5.906,11.327
    c4.351,1.965,9.472,0.686,12.399-3.088l16.287-21.008c31.843,51.565,81.914,94.736,139.664,105.942l21.854,21.854
    c4.036,4.028,10.565,4.028,14.594,0l21.854-21.854c57.75-11.198,107.828-54.377,139.672-105.942l16.287,21.008
    c2.927,3.774,8.048,5.053,12.398,3.088C439.349,366.309,441.79,361.626,440.904,356.937z M237.493,34.839
    c6.9,0,12.513,5.614,12.513,12.514c0,6.9-5.613,12.514-12.513,12.514c-6.9,0-12.515-5.614-12.515-12.514
    C224.979,40.453,230.593,34.839,237.493,34.839z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

UPD В сниппете, здесь на сайте отображается, но если сохранить в отдельный файл `*.svg`, то при запуске в браузерах выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: на сервере по пути `img/symbol/sprite.svg` 404

Comment: Что это значит?  Я не совсем понял.

Comment: вы обращаетесь к картинке которой нет на сервере

Comment: Как мне её правильно подключить?

Comment: для начала нужно чтобы она открывалась по ссылке, по которой Вы ее запрашиваете с сервера, вбейте `img/symbol/sprite.svg` в строку браузера

Comment: Вы неправильно указали id для svg. Правильно будет <use xlink:href="img/symbol/sprite.svg#Capa_1" />

Comment: SVG файл в браузере открывается, но как его подключить его на страницу. Я не знаю. Если нужно что-то приложить дополнительно, могу прикрепить. 
С сервера файл не открывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, уберите первую строчку из SVG файла, она не нужна и мешает открыть SVG файл.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот теперь, файл открывается:

```html
 <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 474.986 474.986" style="enable-background:new 0 0 474.986 474.986;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="XMLID_3_" d="M440.904,356.937l-15.139-80.104c-0.632-3.32-2.842-6.123-5.93-7.501c-3.081-1.386-6.647-1.163-9.542,0.577
    l-69.815,42.086c-4.09,2.464-5.954,7.408-4.514,11.952c1.434,4.552,5.799,7.515,10.559,7.184l27.269-1.902
    c-26.037,34.993-65.227,49.355-110.178,53.036V153.103h22.449c3.62,2.695,8.07,4.343,12.929,4.343
    c12.021,0,21.771-9.742,21.771-21.764c0-12.029-9.75-21.771-21.771-21.771c-4.867,0-9.318,1.656-12.938,4.351h-22.441V86.789
    c12.776-8.494,21.231-22.987,21.231-39.436C284.845,21.247,263.6,0,237.493,0c-26.107,0-47.354,21.247-47.354,47.353
    c0,16.449,8.456,30.942,21.231,39.436v31.474h-22.44c-3.62-2.695-8.07-4.351-12.937-4.351c-12.021,0-21.771,9.742-21.771,21.771
    c0,12.021,9.75,21.764,21.771,21.764c4.859,0,9.309-1.648,12.929-4.343h22.448v229.162c-44.95-3.681-84.14-18.043-110.176-53.036
    l27.269,1.902c4.759,0.331,9.125-2.632,10.558-7.184c1.44-4.543-0.423-9.488-4.513-11.952l-69.816-42.086
    c-2.896-1.74-6.461-1.963-9.542-0.577c-3.088,1.378-5.298,4.181-5.93,7.501l-15.14,80.104c-0.886,4.689,1.555,9.372,5.906,11.327
    c4.351,1.965,9.472,0.686,12.399-3.088l16.287-21.008c31.843,51.565,81.914,94.736,139.664,105.942l21.854,21.854
    c4.036,4.028,10.565,4.028,14.594,0l21.854-21.854c57.75-11.198,107.828-54.377,139.672-105.942l16.287,21.008
    c2.927,3.774,8.048,5.053,12.398,3.088C439.349,366.309,441.79,361.626,440.904,356.937z M237.493,34.839
    c6.9,0,12.513,5.614,12.513,12.514c0,6.9-5.613,12.514-12.513,12.514c-6.9,0-12.515-5.614-12.515-12.514
    C224.979,40.453,230.593,34.839,237.493,34.839z"/>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
<g>
</g>
</svg>
```

- Далее, можете просто скопировать этот код в вашу страничку, это, так
  называемый, инлайн способ добавления SVG в HTML.
  Пока вы не научились уверенно работать с SVG, лучше так делать и всё у вас будет работать.
- Второй способ добавления SVG файлов, которые расположены в отдельной папке
  на сервере сложнее и требуют некоторых знаний

Сначала вы добавляете SVG файл в HTML

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/symbol/sprite.svg">
  Your  browser does not support SVG 
</object>
```

И только потом вызывать иконку по `ID` из этого спрайта:

```
<svg>
      <use  xlink:href="sprite.svg"#icons--icon1"></use>
</svg>
```

Этот способ работает во всех браузерах

- Третий способ, с помощью тега `<img>`- это добавление SVG аналогично
  добавлению растровой картинки, поэтому не будет работать стилизация иконки и
  интерактивность.

```html
<img src="https://www.stupidedia.org/images/a/a3/Gangsta-balz-transparent.svg">
```

Более подробно можно почитать [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=1047)

Comment: Помогло, работает. Но я могу каким-то образом добавить SVG-изображение через:

<svg>
    <use xlink:href=""/>
</svg>

Comment: @Frenc Olesov Пробуйте другими способами они проще - 1. либо просто копируйте содержание svg файла в html, оборачивайте svg в `<div>` и верстайте, как обычно 2 способ -. Добавляйте через тег `<img>`как в ответе